# how to append string to text-file javascript

Tags: javascript, string, file, text, append

Javascript. I want to append some strings to an existing text file. Attention! I don't want to rewrite the file. Just append some strings. Using this code is not successful. The machine says that the function or method is not supported by the object (5, 1).

```js
fsob = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
tf = fsob.OpenTextFile("C:\\Users\\intput.txt", 2, true); 
tf.WriteLine("Поиск по BruteForce:"); 
tf.Close(); 
tf.appendFileSync('C:\\Users\\intput.txt', ",kzzhstna");
```

Comment: What does the documentation have to say about `Close()` and `appendFileSync()`? How does the latter indicate something went wrong?